# How to Restrict a post Request with basic auth in symfony 4.4

Tags: authentication, routes, symfony4

I need to protect a **POST request with basic auth**
like http://host/import/myfile in Symfony 4.4

**In security.yaml**, I tried this but It doesn't work

```html
  providers:
   authorized_users:
         http_basic:
            - identifier: '%env(HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME)%'
            - password: '%env(HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD)%'
   firewalls:
         secured_area:
            methods: [POST]
            pattern: ^/import/myfile
            provider: authorized_users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer, hope that will help !

```html
    providers:
        authorized_users:
            memory:
                users:
                    "%env(HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME)%":
                        password: '%env(HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD)%'
                        
     firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/import/myfile
            stateless: true
            http_basic:
                provider: authorized_users
```